# pwsh command with python subprocess is not working when using IIS server

Tags: python, windows, powershell, iis, iis-7.5

I am running one api using flask . in that I have a powershell script . I am calling this script in a python program using subprocess and using pwsh(because of POWERCLI which uses powershell higher version). regular powershell is not working .

```
cmd = " path of .ps1 "          
value  = subprocess.Popen(['pwsh',  '-Command', cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = value.communicate()[0] 
data = json.loads(out)
```

I am executing this api in windows server locally . which is working fine and giving required data. as soon as I am hosting this in IIS server. this is not giving any output.

1 -This is the error generated by python script when running from IIS .
The term 'Set-PowerCLIConfiguration' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.\to Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have already installed the powercli using : Install-Module VMware.PowerCLI -Scope AllUsers
As per the error looks like powercli setting needs some thing to update for IIS . Please guide me on this

2- I tried with full path of pwsh along with .exe . but that itself got error. not sure it take pwsh.exe full path.
3- My other scripts which are using regular powershell are working fine with IIS server.

```
value = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', cmd], shell=True, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

issue is when I use pwsh alog with IIS server,
Is there anything I am missing or need to add in command with pwsh.
I used subprocess.run also. but in IIS both are not working.

Comment: You are using two different commands. `Powershell` != `pwsh`. Are you sure `pwsh` is installed and on the PATH?

Comment: @C.Nivs Pwsh is installed and it's working fine. also when i run same file  directly it works with pwsh in same server(just validation that it's installed fine) . only when I host the api using IIS , it dowsnt work . it doesn't execute evn the first line, simply not considering the script which we are passing in sub process command.

Comment: @C.Nivs I managed to get below error when running from IIS. The term 'Set-PowerCLIConfiguration' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.\to Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. but I have already installed the powercli using : Install-Module VMware.PowerCLI -Scope AllUsers As per the error looks like powercli setting needs some thing to update for IIS .  Even in get-module Command I can see it. Please guide me on this

Comment: Make sure the path to the PowerCLI module is included in the PSModulePath environment variable for the IIS process.
To check the current value of PSModulePath for an IIS process, you can run the following command in PowerShell: `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")`

Comment: If the path to the PowerCLI module does not exist, you can add it with:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $env:PSModulePath + ";C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules", "Machine")`

Replace "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" with the actual path of your PowerCLI module installation.

Comment: @YurongDai I reinstalled  the powercli modules , it is in below path only .
.    Now Set-PowerCLIConfiguration error is not coming. but it is not generating any output. it's giving result - "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" . same thing is working fine when i run the app.py locally in same system. just for debugging purpose i tried to create a new object in first line of ps1 script. it is not even creating that object from IIS . looks like IIS server is not executing anything  that is running using pwsh in subprocess command .

Comment: @YurongDai below is the output when i run cmd using admin - PS C:\Windows\system32> [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;
PS C:\Windows\system32> pwsh
PowerShell 7.3.6
PS C:\Windows\System32>

Comment: This is how I am passing the ps1 in pwsh -  cmd = " \path\.ps1 '"+ name +"'"    
        result = subprocess.Popen(['pwsh',  '-Command', cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out = result.communicate()[0]  
        data = json.loads(out) 
which is giving desired results in local execution .How to check whether IIS server is taking correct pwsh and powercli  or any other suggestion so I can solve